# Convertir un String a formato date Time en PHP

Tags: php

Una consulta,

Tengo una funcion la cual al entregarle una fecha especifica me retorna el primer dia de la semana de la fecha entregada(hasta aca no hay problema).

El problema es que la funcion necesita un parametro del formato "DateTime", y hasta el momento no he podido convertir un String y que la funciona me funciona correctamente.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST)){        

         $new_date = $_POST['today']; // capturo la fecha que viene de un DatePicker

         $fecha = new datetime();
         $fechafinal = $fecha->createFromFormat('d-m-y', $new_date);        

        // $specifiedDate = new DateTime('10/09/2019'); este es el codigo original y funciona bien cuando al fecha se escribe manualmente.

        $date = firstDayOf('week', $fechafinal);
        echo $date->format('l, jS F Y');


    }
?>
```

PD: este es el primer codigo en PHP y web que realizado, y estoy un poco perdido con el tema de las conversion de formato.

Comment: ¿Cómo es la fecha que recoge en el POST y que guardas en `$new_date`? Pon un ejemplo del formato de la misma.

Comment: A. cedano, el formato que se recogue del "POST "es "10/24/2019", el datepicker me tira el formato de forma dd/mm/yyy, yo creo que por esto de las conversiones pasa gran parte de mi problema,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, hay varios errores en tu código:

1. La  clase se llama `DateTime` no `datetime`. Aunque puede que funcione, conviene respetar la convención de nombres.
2. Estarías creando la fecha actual aquí: `$fecha = new datetime();` para luego usarla como objeto que llama a `createFromFormat` ¿? Si he entendido bien, lo que se requiere es conocer el primer día de la semana de la fecha dada.

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
$mData=( !empty ($_POST['today']) ) ? $_POST['today'] : NULL;
    if ($mData) {
        $mFormat='m/d/Y';
        $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat($mFormat, $mData);
        #Cambia la fecha dada al domingo de la semana en curso
        #y le aplica el formato indicado
        $mOutput=$fecha->modify('sunday this week')->format('l, jS F Y');
    } else {
        $mOutput="No hay datos posteados";
    }
echo $mOutput;
```

**Salida:**

```
Sunday, 27th October 2019
```

### Algunas notas

1. En tu comentario dices que recibes las fechas así: `10/24/2019` Esto es un formato del tipo `Mes/Día/Año`, lo digo por el `24`, por eso en el código he declarado esto: `$mFormat='m/d/Y';` si no es así, adecúalo.
2. Aquí se asume que el primer día de la semana es el domingo, por eso he puesto: `$mOutput=$fecha->modify('sunday this week')->format('l, jS F Y');` si el primer día es el lunes, lo cambias por esto: `$mOutput=$fecha->modify('monday this week')->format('l, jS F Y');`

Esta es la forma más simple de obtener el primer día de la semana de una fecha dada.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono a la perfeccion,  y la verdas estoy bastante perdido con el codigo de php, pero de apoco se avanza. gracias nuevamente